# SQL to Join Two Tables with some business conditions

Tags: sql

I have one intresting requirement to achieve. could you please help?
Please find the below tables

****CheckingAccountTable (Assume Table Name - CAT )**

```
AccountNo  TransactionId    BalanceID       Balance1
123           080              103             $30
123           081              103              $20
123           082              103              $10
123           083              62              $0
123           084              63              $0  
123           085              64              $0
123           086              65              $0
123           087              66              $0  
124           090              103             $3
124           091              103             $2
124           092              103             $1
124           093              72              $0
124           094              73              $0  
124           095              74              $0
124           096              75              $0
124           097              76              $0
```

**SavingsAccountTable (Assume Table Name - SAT)**

```
BalanceID    Balance2
103                    $0
62                    $15
63                    $12  
64                    $20
65                    $0
66                    $0
72                    $11
73                    $0  
74                    $0
75                    $0
76                    $0
```

**RESULT SHOULD LOOKS LIKE**

```
AccountNo  Count(TransactionId)  Sum(Balance1+Balance2)
123            6                   107
124            4                   17
```

Ok, Here, CAT is the main table and SAT is the sub table to return the balance
I want to find out count of transactionID's and Sum(Balance1 + Balance 2)

Conditions. If the Balance1 OR Balance 2 is 0, I can't take transactionID into count

Am not able to acheive it by doing below

```
SELECT  T.AccountNo,Count(T.TransactionId),
                SUM(T.Balance1 + T.Balance2) 'Stressdays'
        FROM 
                (
                    SELECT  CAT.AccountNo,CAT.Balance1,CAT.BalanceID,CAT,TransactionId  
                            ,CASE   WHEN SAT.BalanceID= 103 THEN
                                        0
                                    ELSE
                                        SAT.Balance2
                                    END AS 'Balance2'
                    FROM    CAT
                            INNER   JOIN  SAT ON CAT.BalanceID = SAT.BalanceID
                            WHERE   CAT.Balance1 <> 0
                            AND     SAT.Balance2 <> 0
                )T
        GROUP BY T.AccountNo
```

Comment: Please describe the problem you are having with your query?  Does it return an error?  Does it return incorrect results?

Comment: I'm in trouble understanding your desired output: how can you have Sum(Balance1,Balance2) = 107 for AccountNo = 123? For any record involved either Balance1 = 0 or Balance2 = 0, so according your request it should be zero... Probably it's my fault, but I don't understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT  CAT.AccountNo, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN CAT.Balance1 <> 0 OR ISNULL(SAT.Balance2,0) <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) CountTransactionId,
        SUM(CASE WHEN CAT.Balance1 <> 0 OR ISNULL(SAT.Balance2,0) <> 0 THEN CAT.Balance1+SAT.Balance2 ELSE 0 END) SumBalance1Balance2
FROM CAT
LEFT JOIN SAT
ON CAT.BalanceId = SAT.BalanceId
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your needs, try this:

```
SELECT cat.AccountNo, Count(TransactionId), SUM(cat.Balance1+sat.Balance2)
FROM cat INNER JOIN sat 
    ON cat.BalanceID = sat.BalanceID
   AND (cat.Balance1 <> 0 OR sat.Balance2 <> 0)
GROUP BY cat.AccountNo
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT C.AccountNo,Count(C.TransactionId) AS [Count(TransactionId)],
     SUM(C.Balance1 + S.Balance2) AS [Sum(Balance1+Balance2)]
FROM SO_CAT C
JOIN SO_SAT S ON S.BalanceID =  C.BalanceID--  AND S.BAlance2 <> 0
WHERE C.BALANCE1 <> 0 OR S.BALANCE2 <> 0
GROUP BY C.ACCOUNTNO
```